# Unity + Atenticação Cadastro + Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity3d

Estou com um problema, criei um app android pelo UnityHub e estou com problemas no cadastro e no banco de dados, sempre ao clicar no botão de cadastro ou de login aparece o erro: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Script do Login/Cadastro (Código C#)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
    public InputField email;
    public InputField password;
    public Text resultText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void SignUp()
    {
        auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text.ToString(), password.text.ToString()).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            // Firebase user has been created.
            resultText.text = "Registrado com sucesso!";
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
                newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });
    }

    public void SignIn()
    {
        auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text.ToString(), password.text.ToString()).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            resultText.text = "Login efetuado com sucesso!";
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });
    }

}
```

Obs: tanto para o cadastro quanto para o login só é necessário o email e a senha, sem necessidade de confirmação alguma.

Erro do botão de login:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro do botão de cadastro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como resolve-los?
Agradeço desde já, é minha primeira vez usando o site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth; // variavel que você utiliza

void Start()
{
    // inicializa uma variavel local, mas não a da classe
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
}
```

Para corrigir só tirar essa nova variavel

```
void Start()
{
    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
}
```